# how to fix this stackoverflow error in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, stack-overflow

I have an item that show data like medicine name  that user will provide in add medicine form  , so when user press on add button , the app return to home screen and show new item with medicine name on it , and I created an edit icon to enable user to change any data in this item, but I want to make edit page like add medicine page and show the current data in it, I use GoRoute to navigate between pages, when I press on edit button , I get this error on red screen.
'stack overflow'

[editmedicineview class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TbBr.png)

[add medicineform class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9E5f.png)

[app router class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL2aV.png)

i want to make the edit screen like add screen and show the current data in edit screen

[add new medicine screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPK4j.png)

i tried to warp the edit view with expanded or singlechildscroll view , but it does not work , I don't know where is the problem

Comment: Post code, not screenshots of code.  In general, a stack overflow is usually indicative of accidental infinite recursion.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 1) You didn't post the stacktrace of the error as it shows in your console, so we can't tell where exactly inside your application the error is happening. 2) You didn't post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so there are parts of the code missing which we can't see. 3) You posted [code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/9997212), so we can't reproduce your code.